# Divide an Array into two according to a filter

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin

My app selling books, when a user buys a book, a pdf file is downloaded to the internal memory of the phone. I have two categories of books and the name of the pdf file has a code to identify it.

Of all the files purchased and therefore downloaded, I have the following code to obtain an array of all the books purchased:

```
   val purchasedBooks: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()

    val directoryFiles = context?.filesDir
    val files = directoryFiles?.listFiles()


    if (files != null) {
        for (aFile in files) {
            purchasedBooks.add(aFile.name)
        }
    }
```

This code returns me in `purchasedBooks`:

```
[ssbook1.pdf, ssbook2.pdf, ssbook3.pdf, aabook1.pdf, aabook2.pdf]
```

I need to have it like this:

```
val ssbooks = [ssbook1, ssbook2, ssbook3] // without .pdf
val aabooks = [aabook1, aabook2]
```

To then show it in a recyclerView by sections:

```
________________
MY SS BOOK
________________
ssbook1
----------------
ssbook2
----------------
ssbook3
________________
MY AABOOK
________________
aabook1
----------------
aabook2
```

Any advice I will be grateful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope the below code help.

```
val arr = listOf("ssbook1.pdf", "ssbook2.pdf", "ssbook3.pdf", "aabook1.pdf", "aabook2.pdf")
val result = arr.map {it.substringBefore(".pdf")}
                .groupBy {it.contains("ssbook")}
                .map { it.value}
println(result) // [[ssbook1, ssbook2, ssbook3], [aabook1, aabook2]]
```

You can use the result 2D array to show sections in recycler view

Comment: Most welocme :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use fun `partition`

> /**  * Splits the original array into pair of lists,  * where *first*
>   list contains elements for which [predicate] yielded `true`,  * while
>   *second* list contains elements for which [predicate] yielded `false`.  */