# Sort / segregrate objects based on its type and create / put it on arraylist

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, arraylist

What i want to attain is to sort the array of object that i currently i have :

MixGroup = [PHP,PHP,PHP,EUR,USD,EUR,EUR,USD,PHP]

what i want to do is to put them into one array into their respective currencies like this :

MixGroup = [PHP[] , EUR[], USD []].

I'm currently new into java programming.

what i can only provide is an objective - c code that does the sorting:

here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {

        NSArray *currencies = @[ @"USD", @"EUR", @"PHP", @"AUD" ];
        NSMutableArray<AccountBalance *> *allAccounts = [NSMutableArray new];

        int numOdDummyAccounts = 100;
        for (int i=0;i<numOdDummyAccounts;i++) {
            int currencyIdx = rand() % [currencies count];
            AccountBalance *dummyBalance = [AccountBalance new];
            [dummyBalance setCurrency:currencies[currencyIdx]];

            [allAccounts addObject:dummyBalance];
        }

        // print out all currencies
        for (int i=0;i<numOdDummyAccounts;i++) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [allAccounts[i] getCurrency]);
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

        // now do the sorting
        NSMutableDictionary<NSString *, NSMutableArray *> *groupedResult = [NSMutableDictionary new];
        [allAccounts enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(AccountBalance * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
            NSMutableArray *currencyArray = [groupedResult objectForKey:[obj getCurrency]];
            if (currencyArray) {
                [currencyArray addObject:obj];
            } else {
                NSMutableArray *newCurrencyArray = [NSMutableArray new];
                [newCurrencyArray addObject:obj];
                [groupedResult setObject:newCurrencyArray forKey:[obj getCurrency]];
            }
        }];

        // print out all grouped currencies
        NSMutableArray<NSMutableArray *> *arrayOfArrays = [NSMutableArray new];
        for (NSString *currency in groupedResult.allKeys) {
            NSMutableArray *currentCurrency = [groupedResult objectForKey:currency];
            [arrayOfArrays addObject:currentCurrency];
            NSLog(@"Accounts with currency %@: ", currency);

            // print out all accounts with this currency
            for (int i=0;i<[currentCurrency count];i++) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [currentCurrency[i] getCurrency]);
            }
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

what it does its creating an array and put all relative currencies into one array and it will create another array if the currency is not relative. resulting into:

AllCurrencies[] = [PHP[] , EUR[] , USD[] ] 
where when i call the AllCurrencies.get(0).
it will print all PHP, and so on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52108649/7972699
here is a solution of your problem solved in kotlin i think we can achive the same using lambda and streams  in java8. And for dynamic generation of new array for each currency use recursion

Comment: @ANMOLSRIVASTAVA this is interesting and brilliant but then i don't use kotlin and i cleary have no idea about lambda and streams. sorry.

Comment: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2015/07/how-to-do-group-by-in-java-8.html

read this it's a good sample for your code logic